# MongoDB range query on entire embedded document value

Tags: mongodb, indexing, bson

Assume we have a collection `foo` with index `{tag: 1}` where `tag` is a single key-value pair (there are a lot more details in my actual use-case, but I'm trying to distill down the problem):

```
{_id: 1, tag: {bar: "BAR"}}
{_id: 2, tag: {baz: "BAZ"}}
```

When I query `{tag: { $gte: { baz: MinKey() }}}`, it returns BOTH documents (unexpected).

When I query `{tag: { $gte: { baz: "" }}}`, it returns only `{_id: 2, tag: {baz: "BAZ"}}` (expected).

According to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects, BSON objects are ordered: 1) by field names and 2) by field values.

So why does `{tag: { $gte: { baz: MinKey() }}}` return `{_id: 1, tag: {bar: "BAR"}}` when `bar` is NOT GREATER THAN `baz`?

Comment: `tag` is an object. `"tag.baz"` is a field. I think you are comparing fields, not objects.

Comment: No, I am trying to compare the entire embedded document/object. For example, `{someStringA: "abc"}` is less than `{someStringB: "abc"}` because `someStringA` is less than `someStringB`. Also, `{someInt: 123}` is less than `{someInt: 456}` because `someInt` == `someInt` but `123` is less than `456`

Comment: [Query Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#query-embedded-documents) from the MongoDB Manual has examples of Query Exact Matches on Embedded Document _and_ Query Fields of an Embedded Document.

Answer (score 0):

Note the command a few lines down in the documentation you linked:

> Non-existent Fields
>
> The comparison treats a non-existent field as if it were an empty BSON Object. As such, a sort on the a field in documents { } and { a: null } would treat the documents as equivalent in sort order.

This is telling you that non-existent fields and fields set to null are treated specially.

In order for the documents `{}` and `{a: null}` to be equivalent in sort order, the sort algorithm must be considering the missing sort field to be present, and have a value of `null`.

If you explicitly add the missing field, just to see how it looks, the ordering makes more sense.

The filter `{tag: { $gte: { baz: MinKey() }}}` applied to `{_id: 1, tag: {bar: "BAR"}}` is essentially comparing `{baz: MinKey()}` with `{baz: null, bar: "BAR"}`.

Near the top of the documentaion you linked it states that `MinKey` is less than `null`, so that is the proper ordering.

**EDIT**

In general, querying is most efficient when the fieldnames are not themselves data.  In terms of a tabular database, which columnn would contain "baz"?

A slight change in the schema would simplify this type of query.  Instead of `{tagname: tagvalue}`, use `{k:tagname, v:tagvalue}`.  You could then index `tag.k` and/or `tag.v`, and query on `tag.k` to find all documents with a "baz" tag, querying tags with inequality operations would work more intuitively.

```
db.collection.find({"tag.k":{$gte:"baz"}})
```

Exact matches could be done with elemMatch like

```
db.collection.find({tag: {$elemMatch:{k:"baz",v:"BAZ"}}})
```

If you really need the returned documents to contain `{tagname: tagvalue}`, the `$arrayToObject` aggregation operator can do that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      "tag.k": {$gte: "baz"}
  }},
  {
    $addFields: {
      tag: {$arrayToObject: [["$tag"]]}
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4a-TvJXeHbA)

Comment: I think this MIGHT be an answer, but since we are treating the entire embedded document as a value, it also MIGHT NOT be the answer. I have a question filed over at mongo, if you care to follow: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-51258

Comment: Particularly why I think this MIGHT NOT be the answer, since we are querying/comparing the entire embedded doc as a value, according to the documentation link, field names are supposed to be compared. I believe BSON documents maintain order too.

Comment: Agreed, and the only way sort a document with a field missing the same as a document containing that field with a null value is to consider that the fields exists in both documents, implicitly adding missing fields to the second operand.

Comment: I don't know if that is necessarily true. If BSON documents are regarded as ordered lists of key-value pairs (which I think they are), they can be compared even with missing fields. The serialized BSON is an ordered list of kv pairs.

Comment: The fields are stored in the order they are added to the document. i.e. `{a:1,b:1}` is not equal to `{b:1,a:1}`.  When sorting in memory, a sort key is generated according to the sort spec provided, so the fields in the sort key document are added in the same order.

Comment: I think you have a point about the documentation not quite matching the behavior of the server:`bsonWoCompare({"notakey":true},{ "bar" : "BAR" })` is `25`, but `bsonWoCompare({"notakey":1},{ "bar" : "BAR" })` is `-5`.  I don't see how that's possible unless it considers the value (or at least the type) of the field before the field name.